# europasscv - trying to create table

Tags: tables, europasscv

I'm trying to get a table within to make better use of space, and avoid all the white space on the right, but I get big gaps. This gives me a big huge space

```
\begin{tabular}{m{1cm} m{1cm}|m{1cm}}
\cline{2-3}
\ecvblueitem[5pt]{\begin{myfont}03/18--07/18\end{myfont}} 
{\begin{myfont}\textcolor{ecvsectioncolor}{position} $\:$ $\:$ 
\textcolor{ecvtextcolor}{employer}\end{myfont}}
\ecvitem[5pt]{\begin{myfont}\textcolor{ecvtextcolor}{duties}\end{myfont}}{
\begin{myfont}
\textcolor{ecvtextcolor}{
{
\begin{ecvitemize}
{\item blah blah blah
\item yak yak yak}
\end{ecvitemize}
}
}\end{myfont}
} & & \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

I want it like this below but with the duties to the left underneath employer. Can anyone help? (apologies that I'm so bad at this)

[image]

Comment: Why did you delete the images? With the images your question is clearer! And my answer tries to recreate the layout shown in your image!

Comment: If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). Please see that is the way here to say "Thank you for your help"!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

% This is a simple template for a LaTeX document

\documentclass{europasscv} % use defaults

\begin{document} 

Just one Work Experience section

to show structure in question per the template so fonts are within master not here

\ecvtitle{March 2018 -- July 2018}{Position}
  \ecvitem{}{Employer \newline Address (United Kingdom)}
  \ecvitem{}{
  \begin{ecvitemize}
      \item evaluating blah blah blah
      \item yak yak yak
  \end{ecvitemize}
  }
  \ecvitem{}{\ecvhighlight{Business or sector}\quad European institution}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your given code snippet are several issues:

1. Never use environment `table` in this case, you really do not want your table floating around your cv ...
2. You missed the leading `\begin{table}` in your code ...
3. You can not mix commands of the class `europass-cv` and environment `tabular` in that way you did ...

To get what you want you have two possibilites, the first one is done only with commands provided by your used class, the second one is done by additional loading of package `tabularx` and using environment `tabularx`:

```
% Possibility one % <========================================
\ecvblueitem{03/18--07/18}%
{%
  \textcolor{ecvsectioncolor}{position} $\:$ $\:$ 
  \textcolor{ecvtextcolor}{employer}
}
\ecvitem{\textcolor{ecvtextcolor}{duties}}{duties %
\begin{ecvitemize}
{\item blah blah blah
\item yak yak yak}
\end{ecvitemize}
}

% Possibility two % <========================================
%\usepackage{tabularx}
\ecvblueitem{03/18--07/18}%
{%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{l@{~}l@{~}X}
\textcolor{ecvsectioncolor}{position} & employer & \\
                                      & duties   & \textbullet\ blah blah blah \\
                                      &          & \textbullet\ yak yak yak
\end{tabularx}
}
```

Please see the following complete mwe (based on the example cv of the class (sic!)):

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494707/europasscv-trying-to-create-table
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
% !TEX program = pdflatex
% !TEX spellcheck = en_GB
\documentclass[english,a4paper]{europasscv}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\ecvname{Katie Smith}
\ecvaddress{12 Strawberry Hill, Dublin 8 Éire/Ireland}
\ecvmobile{+353 555 123 555}
\ecvtelephone{+353 127 6689}
\ecvworkphone{+353 999 888 777}
\ecvemail{smith@kotmail.com another@email.com}
\ecvhomepage{www.myhomepage.com www.another-homepage.com}
% \ecvgithubpage{www.github.com/smith}
% \ecvgitlabpage{www.gitlab.com/smith}
% \ecvlinkedinpage{www.linkedin.com/in/katie-smith}
% \ecvorcid[label, link]{0000-0000-0000-0000}
\ecvim{AOL Messenger}{katie.smith}
\ecvim{Google Talk}{ksmith}

% \ecvgender{Female}
\ecvdateofbirth{1 March 1975}
\ecvnationality{Irish}

% \ecvpicture[width=3.8cm]{picture.jpg}

% \date{}

\begin{document}
\begin{europasscv}

\ecvpersonalinfo

\ecvbigitem{Job applied for}{European project manager}

\ecvsection{Work experience}

\ecvtitle{August 2002 -- Present}{Independent consultant}
\ecvitem{}{National Youth Council of Ireland\newline 3 Montague Street, Dublin 2, D02 V327, Ireland}
\ecvitem{}{Evaluation of European Commission youth training support measures for youth national agencies and young people}


\ecvblueitem{03/18--07/18}%
{%
  \textcolor{ecvsectioncolor}{position} $\:$ $\:$ 
  \textcolor{ecvtextcolor}{employer}
}
\ecvitem{\textcolor{ecvtextcolor}{duties}}{duties %
\begin{ecvitemize}
{\item blah blah blah
\item yak yak yak}
\end{ecvitemize}
}

%\usepackage{tabularx}
\ecvblueitem{03/18--07/18}%
{%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{l@{~}l@{~}X}
\textcolor{ecvsectioncolor}{position} & employer & \\
                                      & duties   & \textbullet\ blah blah blah \\
                                      &          & \textbullet\ yak yak yak
\end{tabularx}
}

\ecvtitle{March 2002 -- July 2002}{Internship}
\ecvitem{}{European Commission, Youth Unit, DG Education and Culture \newline 200, Rue de la Loi, 1049 Brussels (Belgium)}
  \ecvitem{}{
  \begin{ecvitemize}
      \item evaluating youth training programmes and the partnership between the Council of Europe and European Commission
      \item organizing and running a 2 day workshop on non-formal education for Action 5 large scale projects focusing on quality, assessment and recognition
      \item contributing to the steering sroup on training and developing action plans on training for the next 3 years. Working on the Users Guide for training and the support measures
  \end{ecvitemize}
  }
  \ecvitem{}{\ecvhighlight{Business or sector}\quad European institution}

\end{europasscv}

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

I personaly would not use possibility 2, possibility 1 looks better, even if it does not fit totally what you want ...