# Starting bullet item on the same line

Tags: spacing, europasscv

In Europass CV format I am using EcvItemize layout within the ‘ItemInset’ (Insert -> Custom Insets -> BlueItemInset) 
The out output result is:
[image]

Here is the code for Image 1

```
\ecvblueitem{Skills}{
\begin{itemize}
\item MATLAB, \LaTeX{}
\item C/C++, Assembly, Python
\end{itemize}
}
```

I want the itemized content start from the same line or leveled with the heading "skills" like this:
[image]

I tried to research and found some similar example here [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494707/europasscv-trying-to-create-table/494719). still not able to get desired output. Anyone can help me.

Comment: Please post a minimal code reproducing the problem.

Comment: I am not much familiar with the lyx environment, just a beginner.   I tried following command in preamble `\ecvbluesubitem{\linewidth}[t]{Computer Skills}`. Anyother way or command  to modify preamble to get above mentioned result?

Comment: Can't you post a (small) *complete* code, reproducing your problem?

Comment: I am editing the given example file europass cv by lyx. i just entered the above code in preamble

Comment: To post a `.lyx` file as an example here, open the file in a text editor (e.g. Notepad), select all the text, copy it, and paste it into your question. After pasting it in, select it and hit Ctrl+K (or click the button marked `{}`). Before you do that, please remove as much content as possible from the document.